# Visual basic forms button click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
  Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click, btn7.Click, btn9.Click
        'PictureBox1.Location = [What should I type here].Location

    End Sub
```

Is it possible that for any button I clicked the location of the "picture box" will change its location same to the button that I have clicked. I know that I can assign the location individually in each "button click events" but maybe there's other(simpler) way to it.

Sorry for my bad English .

Comment: VBA is Visual Basic for Application, a version of VB embedded into Office (and some other) applications. It is quite different from VB .NET. You should change the tag you used from vba to vb.net.

Comment: This is a VBA forum, but I believe, you can use the Sender to tell you what you need, sender.left etc.

Comment: ok thanks ... I have changed the tags .

Comment: PictureBox1.Location = Sender.Location works!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PictureBox1.Location = sender.Location
```

Or this could place your Picturebox location step by step:

```
'Changing X axis
PictureBox1.Left = sender.Left
'Changing Y axis
PictureBox1.Top = sender.Top
```